# Python SKLearn Train-Test_split X_test error: ValueError: Unexpected input dimension 29, expected 28

Tags: python, valueerror, sklearn-pandas

I am at the end of my Colab notebook, and am trying to complete the model_rf.predict(X_test), however, I keep receiving this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-37eb82f98898> in <module>()
      2 submission = pd.DataFrame()
      3 submission['id'] = X_test.index
----> 4 submission['status_group'] = model_rf.predict(X_test)
      5 
      6 submission.to_csv('submission2.csv', index=False)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/category_encoders/ordinal.py in transform(self, X, override_return_df)
    196         # then make sure that it is the right size
    197         if X.shape[1] != self._dim:
--> 198             raise ValueError('Unexpected input dimension %d, expected %d' % (X.shape[1], self._dim,))
    199 
    200         if not list(self.cols):

ValueError: Unexpected input dimension 29, expected 28
```

All of my code prior to this section worked perfectly, but I cannot get past this error. I have not been able to find any questions/answers specific to this error. Here is the code in the cell that triggers the aforementioned error (please note that, while not mentioned in the code below, all necessary imports have been made):

```
X_test = wrangle("test_features.csv")
submission = pd.DataFrame()
submission['id'] = X_test.index
submission['status_group'] = model_rf.predict(X_test)

submission.to_csv('submission2.csv', index=False)
```

Thoughts? And thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: You're going to need to provide us with a little bit more context than what is above. The error is quite simple - the model was trained on 28 parameters but you are inputting a training dataset with 29, so double-check both your training set and test set and compare their dimensions

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to see what I can do to adjust that.